# Parsing String to a Short Mask

Tags: java, parsing, java-io, short, bitmask

Good day.

I'm working with the Tinkerforge Java API to do some programming.

I ran into a Problem, where i've to create a short Mask looking something like:

"0b11011011"

I'm using the following code to parse my config into the Mask Required:
I'm using a Char Array as an easy way to modify the mask, and Parsing it to a String , and using short.parseshort to create the short mask.

```
    //Code Before...
    log.debug("Calculating I Mask for Port A");
    Mask = CalculateIMask(A);
    log.debug("Recieved Mask: " + Mask);
    //Applying Mask to the IOPort
    IO.setPortConfiguration('a', Mask, 'i', true);
    //...

public short CalculateIMask(List<IOPort> IOPL)
{

    char[] Mask = {'0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0'};
    for(IOPort IOP : IOPL)
    {
        if(IOP.isInput())
        {
            log.debug("Setting Pin: " + IOP.getPin() + " to 1");
            Mask[Integer.valueOf(IOP.getPin())] = '1';
        }
    }
    String SMask = String.valueOf(Mask);
    log.debug("Returning Mask: " + SMask);
    return Short.parseShort(SMask, 2);
}
```

The Log looks something like this.

```
[2016-09-16 13:06:48,252] DEBUG [IO16Register] Calculating I Mask for Port A 
[2016-09-16 13:06:48,252] DEBUG [IO16Register] Setting Pin: 0 to 1 
[2016-09-16 13:06:48,252] DEBUG [IO16Register] Setting Pin: 2 to 1 
[2016-09-16 13:06:48,252] DEBUG [IO16Register] Returning Mask: 10100000 
[2016-09-16 13:06:48,252] DEBUG [IO16Register] Recieved Mask: 160
```

The IO.setPortConfiguration does not throw an error, but also does not apply my mask, i suppose it has something to do with the Short.parseShort.

Also the Second Logfile after Parsing does not show the correct mask.

I'm struggling with this issue for a while now, i also tried using a

```
short[] Mask = {'0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0'};
```

instead of the char Array. and using a simple for

```
(short Piece : Mask)
```

to apply all the pieces to one short, but the log resulted in showing: "48484948494848".

I hope someone can give me some advice, i looked in some of the threads, but none of those seem to help me with my problem.

Thank you

Sincerly

Fabian95qw

//edit: The Problem was caused by missing authentication before trying to modify the settings.

I was doing that beforehand, but forgot i swallowed the exception without applying it to the logfile...

com.tinkerforge.TimeoutException: Did not receive response in time for function ID -1
        at com.tinkerforge.DeviceBase.sendRequest(DeviceBase.java:169)
        at com.tinkerforge.BrickletIO16.getIdentity(BrickletIO16.java:502)
        at nucom.module.tinkerforge.bricklets.IO16.ReloadConfig(IO16.java:85)

One Problem remains: How the Binary appends to the Brick:

I'm generating the Following:

Binary: ==0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

Port No:==0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7

But the Program Appends it in this Direction:

Binary: ==0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

Port No:==7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0

Now i just need to modify the code to correctly invert it...

//edit: And i've done it.

I'm using this Code Snipped to correctly generate my mask.

```
public short CalculateIMask(List<IOPort> IOPL)
{

    char[] Mask = {'0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0'};
    for(IOPort IOP : IOPL)
    {
        if(IOP.isInput())
        {
            log.debug("Setting Pin: " + IOP.getPin() + " to 1");

            //Old Code Piece:
            //Mask[Integer.valueOf(IOP.getPin())] = '1';

            Mask[7-Integer.valueOf(IOP.getPin())] = '1';
        }
    }
    String SMask = String.valueOf(Mask);
    log.debug("Returning Mask: " + SMask);

    return Short.parseShort(SMask, 2);
}
```

Comment: Well, 10100000 is 160 in base 10, so there doesn't seem to be a problem with the code here. What's your problem exactly ? where does de short does not apply as a mask ? Maybe it's an endianness problem, you want 00000101 instead ?

Comment: Hello Asoub, i found out why the mask did not apply, it was a missing authentication before trying to modify the settings.

But now, that i can apply the mask i just noticed, now, there is an error somwhere in the process, because i tried modifying the port 1, but end up modifying the port 7 instead. is there an error in my code?

Comment: You should update your question with error details (stacktrace) and also change the title to include Java's IO Port

Comment: Hallo Asob. I added some text, also the Stacktrace i previously swallowed without an exception, and i modified the Tags. Now there is only one Problem remaining...